# How to install extension/

Tags: php, linux

I read a tutorial about file upload progress bar, 
And they say there that I need the `uploadprogress` extension.

Now I search in google how to install and I find some staff, all says about running commands an sets things on php.ini file.

But I dont know where should I run those commands, I buy hosting from company and I have DirectAdmin conrol panel.

Also I dont know which commands should I run, and if I need to download the extension or wo write site address.

I search for the php.ini file in my ftp and I didnt find it, its says that I dont have access to it?

I running php 5 on linux server.

Thanks for helping

Comment: You can refer to [this](http://php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.php) manual about installing PECL extension. I suggest you first try it on your local computer to get better understanding of what needs to be done, then see if your hosting provider can give you what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ask your hosting provider if you have access to the php.ini file on your server, if you do - ask for the SSH username and password (if you don't have them already). Once you've done that, follow [this guide](https://www.drupal.org/node/1332446).

If you don't have access to either the php.ini or SSH, then you wont be able to make the modification and you should [get yourself a cheap hosting with someone like DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/?refcode=4869dc3fd68b) (I use them and they're awesome)

Comment: Hey @JakeBown, thanks for the comment, I get username and password to ssh, but how can I connect there? In the guide you gave wrote only some commands, where I put them?

Comment: Hi Nati, you want to get your username, password and IP address of your server and put it as follows: ssh username@server then hit enter where it will ask for your password. Mine looks something like this jake@183.62.17.323 and then put in my password. -- also, if you get an error, what are you using to SSH?

Comment: Sorry on my ignorance, Where I need to write "ssh username@server" ?

Comment: @Nati323 no problem, if you're using a Mac the. Just open up Terminal - if on windows download the program PuTTY. Any other queries just ask :)

Comment: Thanks, I download the program, I insert the host and choose SSH In the Session menu, its open this window http://srv1.jpg.co.il/7/55ef3438c8e1f.png I wrote the user name (root), and now its stackm I cant write anything

Comment: Have you written your password in the screen you posted above?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89098/discussion-between-nati323-and-jake-bown).